# Adjust content search picture web part size

Tags: content-search-web-part

I created a content search picture web part. But it seems displayed not so good as I want. There is a black space in the bottle. And there is a blank area in the right side as below shown.
How should I do to adjust the picture as my idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify your CSS!

The problem is, that the picture is not the same size as the box and resized to box width.

looks like the box has a fixed height and with:

something like that:

```
.box{
width: 320px;
height: 80px;
}

.box img{
width: 320px;
height: auto;
}
```

maybe you can set the picture as `background-image` and then set the `background-size: cover;`

or something like that to fit the result to your needs!

check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover) out for more background css info: